# Where are the 24-hour keilim mikvaot in NYC?

Tags: product-recommendation, mikvah-ritual-bath, tevilas-keilim-dipping, keilim-purity

Can anyone help me find a 24-hour keilim mikvah in NYC, preferably Manhattan or Brooklyn? (NOT the East River.) There must be a ton of them, but it's surprisingly impossible to find a listing online.

Comment: I've heard there's a 24-hour person-Mikva in (or near) Monsey. If needed that ought to do the trick.

Comment: @DoubleAA Monsey is about 1 hour drive from Manhattan. And that's if you drive very early on Sunday morning.

Comment: @DanF Yes, but if you need a 24-hour Mikva, it's probably very, very important and around 2am.

Comment: I think there may be one in Far Rockaway next to the "White Shul". When I was at the regular men's mikvah, I noticed that before entering the main mikvah there was a small keilim mikvah on the side. I also noticed that it had a "punch code" lock, and the code to unlock it was in Hebrew. (I assume that anyone knowing Hebrew could decipher it, and I guess they want to keep out non-Hebrew speaking Gentiles ... or Jews, too!) Before I research further, would this location be acceptable for you? Curious - why would you need to immerse a pot at 3 A.M. ?

Comment: You may want to start with this http://www.mikvahminder.com/details/mikvah-of-far-rockaway.html. I'll see if I can reach them a bit later. But, the site, has a map of all mikva'ot throughout U.S. and other parts of the world. You may just have to call a number of a location convenient to you. If you do find something, please post an answer so that all of us will know.

Comment: For some reason you ruled out the East River. Are you also ruling out the various inlets on the south shore of Brooklyn such as Mill Basin, Fresh Creek, Gerritsen Creek and Jamaica Bay for the same reason? (I'm not sure what that reason is.)

Comment: @DanF I once toiveled stuff in the river and will never do it again. It's dark, dirty, and really dangerous for a single woman at night. Moreover after doing so once I learned that the river wasn't a kosher mikvah AND it had E. coli. :-( I need the late-hours mikvah because it's the only time I am motivated enough to toivel dishes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just called Washington Heights Keilim mikvah. Located on Bennet Ave. between W. 185 St and W. 186 St. Manhattan.

Phone: 212 923 3582

The woman told me that the entrance is to the right of the shul. There is a black gate. The gate requires a code which is written in Hebrew on the gate (Thanks Monica, for confirming this), with the Hebrew letters conveying their numerical value corresponding to the code (Aleph = 1, etc.) After entering the gate, there is a passageway then steps going down to the keilim mikvah. The code to the mikvah door is the same as for the gate. It is a "manual" punch lock (not electronic). She also explained that the mikvah is open 24-hours / day. You may want to call yourself to verify the exact instructions. I tried viewing the place on Google Earth, and I'm not sure what gate she is referring to.

I will advise that parking in the area is almost impossible, so, if you go, I advise having one person sitting in the car while you and your keilim are in the mikvah area. (I used to live near that area, and occasionally visit.)

---

Another keilim Mikvah that is open 24 hours and may be closer to you is the

[Far Rockaway Mikvah](http://www.mikvahminder.com/details/mikvah-of-far-rockaway.html)

1121 Sage Street

Phone: 718 327 9727

Sage St. is one way going from Central Ave. and ending at Empire Blvd. As soon as the street narrows and curves to the left, you will see a narrow driveway on your **right**. Look carefully for it, as it can be easy to miss, and going around the block is not that simple! Going up the driveway, you will see an agudah (has Hebrew on the front of the building) and the mikvah is the next shorter building after the agudah on your right. The keilim mikvah is the 1st door on the right when you face the building. I was there recently, and the door to the keilim mikvah was left open, and no one was there. They left a dipping basket in the mikvah. You can park your car right next to the door! They ask that you not leave boxes (I assume from newly opened flatware, etc.) in their dumpsters, but take all boxes & garbage with you.

The person said that the place is open 24 hours and there is a Hebrew code on the door to operate a manual push button lock. Though, she says the door is usually slightly open and you just have to turn the handle on top of the door and push it open. (They place the handle on top so that little kids don't easily get in.)

---

I saw a poster in a neighborhood store mentioning a keilim service where someone will pick up the keilim from you, toveil them and deliver them back to you, for a fee, of course.

The number is **516 341 2077** or email **tvilatkeilim@gmail.com**. The top of the poster says "servicing the 5 Towns and Far Rockaway", so if you live outside that area, they may not do it. However, it can't hurt to call or email them and inquire. Perhaps, there is a similar service that will pick up from you.

Comment: Shkoach! Looking forward to long years of middle-of-the-night trips here

Comment: @SAH You're very welcome. And may you and your family enjoy mounds of chulent for many years coming from your toveiled pots ;-)

Comment: DanF Amein! ...Also, FWIW, I think mods were right to keep the mikvah entry code out of this post. I went, true to form, to the Washington Heights mikvah at about 3 a.m. last night, and was severely sketched out by a car with an "IRQ" bumper sticker slowly circling the shul, then following me.

Comment: @SAH I don't know what "IRQ" means. As I surmise that you live in Brooklyn, you may want to try the Far Rockaway location. It's closer, and I think you can park in the driveway right next to the mikvah.

Comment: @SAH I added (edited) another option which may work. If possible, let me know what they said. Shabbat Shalom.

Comment: @SAH I further edited info about the Far Rockaway mikvah. I recommend that one over the Wash. Heights one. I was there recently, and it looks like a far more convenient & safer place for you.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like I won't need to toivel more stuff for awhile, but when I do, I'll keep that option in mind :)