# Is there a keilim mikvah in Williamsburg

Tags: product-recommendation, mikvah-ritual-bath

I have few items I need to toivel. Where can I find a keilim mikvah in Williamsburg?
Unfortunately I couldn't find any good resources online. Google maps didn't help either.
Much appreciated!

Comment: I did a Google search for the terms "Williamsburg new york city mikveh" (or "mikvah") and got a list of hits. I don't actually know where Williamsburg is, so I cannot comment on whether all of these Brooklyn addresses would satisfy you. If you know what zip code you will be in, it might be easier to find a suitable address. The next step, I think, would be to phone the suitable Mikva'os to ask when (or whether) you can bring dishes there.

Comment: how about the river?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77574/where-are-the-24-hour-keilim-mikvaot-in-nyc?r=SearchResults

Comment: Most maps such as mikvah.org/directory will show regular mikvaos and not keilim mikvaos

Comment: Your best bet in that neighborhood is to ask any religiously identifiable person in the street.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Osso Hardware / 38 Lee Ave & Homery Store / 34 Franklin Ave have a Keilim Mikva